# Nav menu for DrawerLayout and tabs for Tablayout next to each other in the app bar?

Tags: android

Im using both a [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) and a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) in my `Activity`. However, **the TabLayout aligns below the AppBar and Nav menu**. I want to **get rid of the App name and replace it with the Tabs**, as the images below show.

[image]
[image]

**How can I achieve this?** Here are my xml files for the activity

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/unselectedTab"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/favoritesGroup"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_calendar"
        android:title="Kalender"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_none"
        android:title=""
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_availabilityList"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_calendar"
        android:title="Tillgänglighet"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_available_jobs"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment"
        android:title="Lediga Jobb"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_contactSc"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:title="Kontakt"/>
</group>

<item android:title="Mina Sidor">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/myPagesGroup"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_commissions"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_commissions"
                android:title="Mina Uppdrag"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_commission_schedule"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_commission_schedule"
                android:title="Uppdragsschema"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_vacation"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_vacation_application"
                android:title="Semesteransökan"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_employment_terms"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_employment_terms"
                android:title="Anställningsvillkor"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_document"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_document"
                android:title="Dokument"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_consultant_agent"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_consultant_agent"
                android:title="Konsultombud"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_file_upload"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_file_upload"
                android:title="Ladda upp intyg"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_tests"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tests"
                android:title="Mina tester"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_matching_jobs"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_matching_jobs"
                android:title="Matchande jobb"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_applications"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_applications"
                android:title="Mina ansökningar"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_profile"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_profile"
                android:title="Min profil"/>
        </group>
    </menu>

</item>

<item android:title="Övrigt">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/generalGroup"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_looking_for_job"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_assignment"
                android:title="Söker du jobb?"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_looking_for_personel"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_people"
                android:title="Söker du personal?"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_office"
                android:title="Om oss"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `Toolbar` (`@+id/toolbar`) from the `AppBarLayout` in `app_bar_main.xml`. This will make the `TabLayout` take the place of the tool bar, but then you will have to make a custom implementation of the hamburger icon click.

For example, you can make a separate tab for it and when the user clicks it, open the drawer, and also disable swipe left from your `MIN KALENDER` tab. Or you could get rid of the drawer altogether and put its contents into another tab which would be the one for the hamburger icon (I've seen it done that way in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yatra.base) app).